# Stream corrupted exception - invalid code type AC [java]

Tags: java, multithreading, io, stream, server

I'm trying to develop a Java client-server application, where multiple clients can connect to the server. I start a separate thread for each incoming client, pass the client socket to the thread, and then open a pair of streams to maintain communication. And I got this java.io.StreamCorruptedException - invalid code type AC.

From what I researched, it means that I use a new ObjectOutputStream to write to an existing ObjectInputStream. However, I'm not really sure how to deal with this in my code, tried various places for stream initialization, but I still fail to do it right. The line at which the exception occurs is marked in the Client code. I probably lack some basic understanding in IO streams. Here's my server code, together with thread running a client connection:

```
 public class Server {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

        boolean listeningSocket = true;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(11111);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 11111");
        }

        while(listeningSocket){
            System.out.println("Waiting for a client to connect...");
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Client connected!");
            ConnectThread ct = new ConnectThread(clientSocket);
            ct.start();
            ct.run();
        }
        serverSocket.close();       
    }
```

}

Connect thread:

```
public class ConnectThread extends Thread{

private Socket socket = null;


public ConnectThread(Socket socket) {

    super("ConnectThread");
    this.socket = socket;

}

@Override
public void run(){
    ObjectOutputStream serverOutputStream = null;
    ObjectInputStream serverInputStream = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("check");
        serverOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("check");
        serverInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        serverOutputStream.writeInt(42);
        System.out.println("check");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        try {
            serverOutputStream.close();
            serverInputStream.close();              
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
        //implement your methods here
```

}

and the client:

```
public class Client {

public static void main(String[] arg) {


    Socket socketConnection = null;
    ObjectOutputStream clientOutputStream = null;
    ObjectInputStream clientInputStream = null;
            try {

        socketConnection = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 11111);

        clientOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(
                socketConnection.getOutputStream());
        clientInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(
                socketConnection.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("check");
        System.out.println(clientInputStream.readInt()); // HERE'S WHERE THE EXCEPTION OCCURS

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("The following exception has occured and was caught:");
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    finally{
        try {
            clientOutputStream.close();
            clientInputStream.close();
            socketConnection.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Don't write code like this. You are continuing after exceptions when you can't. Code that depends on the success of code in a prior `try` block should be inside that `try` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix this bit first:

```
        ConnectThread ct = new ConnectThread(clientSocket);
        ct.start();
        ct.run();
```

Your ConnectThread is a subclass if thread and it will launch a new thread to execute your run method once you call start. So remove ct.run(); and check again. Most likely you try to read from two threads (Accept one and Connect one) from the same socket and it causes your failure.